# iPhone - Loading a new view and a deallocated object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, interface-builder

So I feel like a serious rookie right now, but I have a problem I can't seem to figure out.  I have a barebones app, with literally nothing in it except a login screen and a second view containing a tableview.  When I add the second view after logging in (I have done this like 4 times before...), the table view goes through its delegates and appears that it's going to load, but something happens.  I have enabled my NSZombies, and it appears to be deallocating the new view, right before it appears.

After tracing through it, and building up again piece by piece, it appears to happen after I wire the table to the view as the datasource/delegate in IB.  I have set the view as a UITableViewDelegate, and the methods indeed get fired.  Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this behavior?

Comment: Are you doing some kind of strange view juggling that causes the view to not be retained in the first place?

Comment: When you say "second view", do mean a UIView or a UIViewController that you are presenting somehow?

Comment: I think Matt's question above is the most important info right now. How are you presenting the second view? Are you presenting an entirely new ViewController or are you just adding a subview to your existing view? Either way, please post the code you are using to present the new view. That's the first place to start looking for a problem.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I am literally adding a subview to the main window via `[appDelegate.window addSubview:mainViewController.view];`

Comment: I think, as Dave Anderson pointed out below, the view was being released by the dealloc method.  I didn't realize that that was being called.  (I put a breakpoint on the method to make sure...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added the 'second'view to an exisitng view using addSubview: or added it to some form of UINavigationController or UITabBarController? When you do this it will automatically increase the retain count and whatever code you have releasing the view won't cause is to be deallocated.

In my AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions I have something like;

```
LoginViewController *login = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];    
[login setDelegate:self];

loginNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc]      
                       initWithRootViewController:login];

[window addSubview:[loginNavController view]];
```

And then once login has occured (and succeeded using a protocol/delegate to send the message back to AppDelegate) I call this code;

```
UIViewController *newView1 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
UIViewController *newView2 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
UIViewController *newView3 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

myTabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

myNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] 
                     initWithRootViewController:newView1];

// nav controller now retaining
[newView1 release];

NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:myNavController, 
                                                     newView2, 
                                                     newView3, 
                                                     nil];

[myTabBarController setViewControllers:viewControllers animated:YES];   
[[myTabBarController view] setFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];

[window addSubview:[tabBarController view]];    

// tab bar controller now retaining
[newView2 release];
[newView3 release];

// remove login from application
[[loginNavController view] removeFromSuperview];
```

The AppDelegate has the following declared in the header file;

```
LoginViewController *loginViewController;
UITabBarController *myTabBarController;
UINavigationController *myNavController;
```

In the dealloc method for the AppDelegate these are released.

This gives me my login page and then when that has processed my views with a top nav all controlled using the bottom tab bar.

Hope this helps in some way.

Comment: I am pretty sure this is what was happening.  This logic mirrors mine quite similarly.  Thanks for the response and help

Answer (score 0):

You have either too many `release` (or `autorelease`) calls - or not enough `retain` calls - in your view loading/transitioning code, but it's impossible to be more specific without seeing that code.

What's probably happening is the autorelease pool is being flushed between your view loading and your view being shown, and that's what's leading the behaviour you describe.